In what order should I perform repairs involving a seismic retrofit?
I'm planning to have a seismic retrofit done on an old house (~100 years old). I've noticed sewage leaks on some of the cast iron pipes (with bugs everywhere around them) and rotted columns. Should I find a plumber to fix the sewage leaks and then have pest control to detect and eradicate any infestations and repair/replace any rotted columns before I do the retrofit? Any suggestions what else should I prepare before doing a retrofit? Thanks.

@isherwood I want to maintain plumbing in a crawl space to avoid leakage because moisture, which may lead to infestation, may cause wood to decay more easily. What do you think? Thanks.

Well, your question is rather broad in scope and somewhat subjective. You're asking several things and haven't provided much detail. Please see [ask] and see if you can revise to be more specific.

You should plan what you will do with the retrofit before starting the other things.  The reason being that the changes you plan to make for the retrofit may affect what you do with the plumbing and fixing the wood rot.  For example, if you will need to move a pipe to allow you to add reinforcement for the retrofit, better to do that as part of the plumbing step than to redo the plumbing twice.
Similarly, some of the retrofit changes may obviate wood rot fixes.  E.g. if you need to remove a post and replace it with something stronger or more flexible, no point in fixing the rot.  You might remove the damaged post immediately and put in something temporary or permanent to replace it.  Temporary may be better, due to the possibility of damage before the other things are fixed.  Alternatively, you might leave the damaged post until you are ready for the permanent replacement.  Picking one of those options will depend heavily on the specific circumstance.  I'd prefer the temporary fix to the others in general, but specific circumstances may push you to delay the removal or do the permanent fix ahead of the ideal order.
If you have plumbing issues, you want to fix them before the retrofit and before getting rid of the bugs and fixing the wood rot.  The reason being that plumbing issues may lead to more bugs, more rot, and damage to your retrofit changes.
You want to get rid of the bugs before fixing the wood rot and making retrofit changes.  The reasons being that the bugs themselves may cause damage and addressing the bugs may cause staining, etc.  So get that done before doing fixes and changes.
Fix the wood rot where needed.  The reasons being that the rotten wood may contain more bugs that will do more damage and that the retrofit may block some of the access that you need to fix the wood rot.  As previously discussed, sometimes you will remove to fix the wood rot and later put in the replacement as part of the retrofit.  Temporary solutions may be required in between the removal and replacement steps.
Now that everything is as clean as you can make it, proceed with your retrofit.  You may discover things as you go that will cause changes to the retrofit plan.  This is normal.  Plans often have to change in the face of information not available when the plan was made.  Another reason to favor temporary solutions earlier in the process.
Note that this is the same order that you gave or that appears in this answer.  I'm mostly providing more context as to why and emphasizing the need to plan ahead of making any changes.

The rot is, no doubt, from the water/ sewage, so the logical series of repairs should be as you stated.
Fix the plumbing issues.
Get rid of the bugs.
Repair the wood rot.
Begin your seismic retrofit.
